# Eclipse/maven class differences - how to resolve?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty, junit4, embedded-jetty

Got a web application maven pom file imported in eclipse. No classpath entries are manually created in eclipse. Essentially project is whatever m2e imported.

Project has a test that sets up dummy database, populates the data and then starts jetty server using @BeforeClass annotation.

Everything works fine in eclipse. However when running mvn test command, I get exception

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /app/login. Reason:
>
> Server Error
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/pages/Login.jsp(1,61)
> PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be
> resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Its obvious jsp setting is screwed up but can't figure out why? Its same pom and web.xml file that runs in both eclipse and maven.

I can not use jetty plugin easily as I need to set up lot of things before test starts - e.g. dummy database that test will be using and populate it with test data and other web applications. Besides test works in eclipse, but not on command line.

Comment: Any specific reason you are starting your jetty from your test cases? What if your test cases are standalone?

Comment: @asg, This is supposed to be integration test which does walking across most of the pages and performs testing using htmlunit. We do catch many issues this way even before it gets deployed to QA server

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! My exp with Jetty - Jetty behaves very weirdly for transitive dependencies in eclipse. You may need to close some of the projects in your workspace to get your web project running. Give it a try with Tomcat if time permits for you.